# Scope Isolation & nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Dealing with '&' and isolated scope.

Is it possible to pass a value up through a parent directive? I want to pass id from the textdisp directive to the controller.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <builder removequest="deleteQuestion(id)"></builder>
  </body>
```

ANGULAR:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.deleteQuestion = function(id) {
    alert(id);
  }
});

app.directive('builder', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      removequest: '&'
    },
    template: '<div>Hello how are you? <textdisp removequest=removequest(id)></textdisp></div>'
  }
});


app.directive('textdisp', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      removequest: '&'
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="remove()">Click here!</div>',
    link: function (scope, el) {
      scope.remove = function(id) {
        console.log('workin')
        scope.removequest(1);
      }
    }
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are 2 things going on with your code:

1. When you're placing `removequest="removequest(id)"` that is *calling* the function, and not just referring to the function.
2. I believe that the `&attr` binding isn't returning the function that you're expecting.

[Try this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aivGAGE6ZJIphFCaBOps?p=preview); it essentially uses `{ removequest: '=' }` for bi-directional binding, and `removequest="deleteQuestion"` / `removequest="removequest"` for function references rather than calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little confusing, but you can use object parameter when you need to pass values into your function invoked via `&` binding. Take a look at this code it will make everything clear:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.deleteQuestion = function(id) {
        alert(id);
    }
});

app.directive('builder', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            removequest: '&'
        },
        template: '<div>Hello how are you? <textdisp removequest="removequest({id: id})"></textdisp></div>'
    }
});


app.directive('textdisp', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            removequest: '&'
        },
        template: '<div ng-click="remove()">Click here!</div>',
        link: function(scope, el) {
            scope.remove = function(id) {
                scope.removequest({id: 34534}); // <-- 1.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3OEy39UQlS4EyOu5cq4y?p=preview

Note how you specify `scope.removequest({id: 34534})` parameter to be passed into `<textdisp removequest="removequest({id: id})">`.

Comment: Ah never knew of that before now. Is this more proper than doing '=' like the chosen response?

Comment: I've also never seen that before; how does that work? I suppose it makes sense to use `&attr` on account of the function being called from the parent scope.

Comment: By passing an object like `{id: 34534}` you kind of extend parent scope object with passed object. So you can use those properties like they were in the scope originally. So this way you can pass parameters   into the function.